# Batch File Encryption

Tags: command-line, batch-file, encryption

So im trying to encrypt a password my company uses for putty ssh. Problem is that the PW uses special characters and the encryption/decryption im using isnt working with special characters since its delayedexpansion. Help!

```
@echo off
mode con lines=11
title Crypt
:begin
endlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :header
set map=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890^^!
set /p "command=Encrypt or Decrypt? (e/d):"
if "%command%"=="e" goto ENC
if "%command%"=="d" goto DEC
:MenuError
call :header
echo: ERROR: !command! is an invalid option.
pause
goto begin
:ENC
call :header
set /p "filename=Enter the File name you wish to save the Text under (Eg. Text):"
:ENCpwd
call :header
set /p "text=Enter the text you wish to encrypt (20 char limit, Characters can include [a-z] [A-Z] [0-9] [space]):"
call :header
echo:Encrypting...
:ENC2
set num2=0
set c=
set /a num1=%num1%+1
set /a num3=%num3%+1
if %num3%==21 goto ENC4
for /l %%x in (0,1,19) do set /a inc=%%x+1&if %num3%==!inc! set "c=!text:~%%x,1!"
:ENC3
if %num2%==0 set L=
for /l %%x in (0,1,65) do set /a inc=%%x+1&if %num2%==!inc! set "L=!map:~%%x,1!"
set e%num1%=
if "%c%"=="%L%" set e%num1%=%num2%
if "%c%"==" " set e%num1%=0
set /a num2=%num2%+1
if defined e%num1% goto ENC2
goto ENC3
:ENC4.1
set /a Rnum=%Rnum%-1
:ENC4
set /a Rnum=%Rnum%+1
set rcheck=%random:~0,4%
set /a rcheck2=%rcheck%+63
if %rcheck% LSS 1063 goto ENC4.1
if %rcheck2% GTR 9999 goto ENC4.1
set r%Rnum%=%rcheck%
if defined r20 goto ENC5
goto ENC4
:ENC5
for /l %%x in (1,1,20) do set /a e%%x=!e%%x!+!r%%x!
for /l %%x in (1,1,20) do (
set "estr=!estr!!e%%x!"
set "rstr=!rstr!!r%%x!"
)
echo:!estr!>"%filename%.pwd"
echo:!rstr!>"%filename%.key"
:ENC6
call :header
echo:Encrypting complete^^!
ping -n 3 -i 1 127.0.0.1>nul
goto begin
:DEC
call :header
echo: NOTE: The encrypted file (*.pwd) and Key file (*.key) must be under the same name (Eg. Password.pwd and Password.key)
echo:       AND in the same directory as this batch file.
echo:
set /p "filename=Enter the File name the Encrypted Text was saved under (Eg. Text):"
call :header
if not exist "%filename%.pwd" goto ERRpwd
if not exist "%filename%.key" goto ERRkey
goto DEC2
:ERRpwd
echo: ERROR: !filename!.pwd was not found
pause
goto DEC
:ERRkey
echo: ERROR: !filename!.key was not found
pause
goto DEC
:DEC2
call :header
echo:Decrypting...
set /p "key= "<"%filename%.key"
set /p "pwd= "<"%filename%.pwd"
for /l %%x in (0,4,76) do (
set /a counter+=1
set "k!counter!=!key:~%%x,4!"
set "e!counter!=!pwd:~%%x,4!"
)
:DEC3
set num2=0
set t=
set /a num+=1
if %num%==21 goto DEC5
for /l %%x in (1,1,20) do if %num%==%%x set /a "t=!e%%x!-!k%%x!"
:DEC4
if %num2%==0 set L=blank
for /l %%x in (0,1,65) do set /a inc=%%x+1&if %num2%==!inc! set "L=!map:~%%x,1!"
set t%num%=
if %t%==%num2% set "t%num%=%L%"
if defined t%num% goto DEC3
set /a num2+=1
goto DEC4
:DEC5
for /l %%x in (1,1,20) do if "!t%%x!"=="blank" set "t%%x= "
for /l %%x in (1,1,20) do set "tstr=!tstr!!t%%x!"
call :header
echo:Decrypting complete^^!
Set new=%tstr%
ECHO !tstr!
pause
goto begin
:header
cls
echo:________________________________________________________________________________
echo: Text Encryptor/Decryptor by maniacal
echo:________________________________________________________________________________
exit/b
```

Comment: Why aren't you using SSH keys? Why do you need to encrypt the password, if it's something you're supposed to *know*, not *store*?

Comment: I am not aware of any encryption, at least any encryption that should be used, that doesn't handle special characters properly.